# Extract hashtags from entities.hashtags

Tags: json, r, twitter, twitter-r

We had used a service which download tweets from twitter. Now I want to show the most popular hashtag from the list of hashtags, the problem is the `entities.hashtags` columns in the `json` file have the following format:

```
list(text = c("PimpYourCoffee", "swarovski"), indices = list(c(28, 43), c(56, 66)))
```

Now the hashtags in this line is `PimpYourCoffee` and `swarovski`.

I don't know to get this, and how should I iterate the same function over the list to get list of all hashtags.

Comment: From `l <- list(list(text = c("PimpYourCoffee", "swarovski"), indices = list(c(28, 43), c(56, 66))))` you'd get the tags by `tags <- sapply(l, "[", "text")`.

Comment: @lukeA i have a variable named hashtags which consist of combination of these lines,how i can take tags out of these all lines,there are round about 10K observations,plz help.